# Android :How to design 3D joysticks

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I am going to design an app where i have 3D joysticks that sends some command from app towards arduino via BLE.i searched out alot about 3D joy sticks lib or other source to integrate it within in my app but i am unable to find it.There is some lib on github that gives 2D joysticks functionality but have no 3D design.
But this is not the one that i need.i want to desgin the jostick like below one.
[image]

please any one have any idea how to design it in android..any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can create this design that is very easy, you have to create some drawables with gradient and selector for button and need some images.

**Here is the list of components you need**

1. background image
2. left, right, top bottom navigation images
3. outer circle drawable with gradient color.
4. Inner circle with border of gradient color.
5. And finally two button images one for pressed effect and second for normal state (will be used in selector to make 3D effect).

That is enough to make this design in Android.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi sir thank you for your interest...but i am new to xml and UI so thats why i felt defficult with xml and selectors etc to work with it..

Comment: @mtg At SO No one will give you the whole code, here people will help you to fix your bugs, They will help you if you help yourself first.